# Updating a line in a text file python, object is not iterable

Tags: python

I am trying to update a line in a text file based on the previous line but when i try to update the line I get an 'object not iterable' error.
The file looks like this:

_Revenue =

10

Seats taken =

1

Seats remaining =

199_

My code:

```
FileRead = open(self.fileName, "r")
        lines = FileRead.readlines()
        print(lines)
        for i in range(len(lines)):
            if "Revenue" in lines[i]:
                print("good")
                self.revenue = self.revenue + self.AdditionalRevenue
                print(lines[i+1])
                place = i+1
                lines.insert(place, self.revenue)
        FileRead.close()

        FileWrite = open(self.fileName, "w")
        FileWrite.writelines(lines)
        FileWrite.close()
```

Comment: you open the file as "r" -> read only and then you try to write ;)

Comment: Please provide the complete error message

Comment: @veselindanilov Not true.

Comment: How It will update? It will insert a new object. you might want to do `lines[i+1]=self.revenue`